# Is this a complex sentence with a transitive verb?

Tags: grammar, complex-sentences, transitive-verbs

1) I found myself [nodding with him], agreeing with things I knew to be true.

Is this a complex sentence with a transitive verb?

In this sentence, ''*nodding with him*'' seems to modify ''*myself*'' Because, ''*I found myself*'' could mean ''*I found my soul, my spirit while I was traveling.'' However, with the modifier, it could also mean, I was surprised to discover that we had so much in common. Furthermore, there is no presence of ''be'' which if am I correct reflects a transitive complex sentence. Furthermore, in the past tense, the sentence would be: I was found nodding with him – with the presence of ''be'' it could now be a transitive complex sentence. Moreover, nodding with him respond to a question in Who not in What - With who did she found herself? - Because I had no difficulty to transform the sentence in the past tense and ask a question in *Who*, I would go for a transitive complex sentence. What do you think?

Comment: Is the bit in brackets supposed to be a parenthetical, i.e. outside the structure of the clause?

Comment: Thanks for your question Bill. The square brackets are here to signify the modifier of the COD.

Comment: "Myself" is object of the catenative verb "found" and the subordinate clause "nodding with him" is catenative complement of "found".

Comment: Thanks, Bill. I really appreciate. I didn't learn about catenative verbs, just read about it now. So if I am not wrong, that can't be a transitive complex sentence, am I right? because of the catenative verb.

Comment: It is a transitive construction because "found" has a direct object "myself". Yes, it is a complex sentence because it has a subordinate clause "nodding with him".

Comment: @BillJ It's clear now, I understand. Thanks a lot.